# Failure during creation of a play framework project

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I want to create a project with java and play framework.
I'm working on a linux(Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa) and a windows (win 10) notebooks. On linux, Before attempting a new project creation, I successfully execute an example project. On windows I failed both goals because it doesn't recognize sbt when I attempt to execute an existing project and because of the below problem for a new one.

This is the statement I typed to create the new project:

```
sbt new playframework/play-java.g8
```

This is the output on the console with some request on input:

```
info] welcome to sbt 1.3.12 (Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0_181)
[info] set current project to sandbox (in build file:/home/.../sandbox/)
[info] set current project to sandbox (in build file:/home/.../sandbox/)
Username: pippo
Password: 
Username: pippo
Password: 
Username: pippo
Password: 

https://github.com/playframework/play-java.g8.git: not authorized
```

On windows I fail also to insert values for username and password.

why does sbt ask me to enter a username and password? What kind of value should I enter? Why can't I enter anything in windows in this procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will ask for username/password if the template is not correct, and you have a typo in the template, it should be:

```
sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8
```

not

```
sbt new playframework/play-java.g8
```

[Reference](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/NewApplication)

Comment: I thought that 'play-java-seed' was the name of the project or something similar...